# Автоматическое определение имени вкладки

Tags: c#

Вопрос в следующем: по нажатию кнопки создается вкладка, далее на этой вкладке должно отрисовываться encounternum количество прогрессбаров. И вот не могу понять, как это сделать, а именно как ссылаться на имя только что созданной вкладки, чтобы именно в ней происходила отрисовка.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            encounter_count++;

            int encounternum = Convert.ToInt32(encounter_members.Value);
            string tabpage_name = "Encounter " + encounter_count.ToString();
            tabControl.TabPages.Add(tabpage_name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю изменить процесс создания новой вкладки на следующий:

```
TabPage CurentTP= new TabPage();
CurentTP.Name=tabpage_name;
tabControl.TabPages.Add(CurentTP);
```

Далее можно пользоваться (если в том же методе) созданной вкладкой CurentTP.

Если ссылка на последнюю созданную вкладку требуется в другом методе и не хочется создавать глобальных переменных, которые бы хранили ссылку на последнюю добавленную вкладку, можно просто брать из `tabControl.TabPages` последнюю добавленную вкладку:

```
TabPage LastTP=tabControl.TabPages[tabControl.TabPages.Count()-1];
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже пошел по другому пути) Решил создать экземпляр табпэйджа и в нем прописать прогрессбары с некоторыми свойствами, и сейчас проблема в том, чтобы в коде добавить эти самые бары)

Comment: @chydik, Не совсем понял про экземпляр и прогрессбары... Вы решили создать "шаблон" вкладки, копии которого будете добавлять табконтрол?